# How do I define the record structure of ebcdic file?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, cobol, ebcdic, copybook

I have ebcdic file in hdfs I want to load data to spark dataframe, process it and load results as orc files, I found that there is a open source solution which is cobrix [cobrix](https://github.com/AbsaOSS/cobrix), that allow to get data from ebcdic files, but developer must provide a copybook file which is a schema definition.

A few line of my ebcedic file are presented in the attached image.
I want to get the format of copybook of the ebcdic file, essentially I want to read the **vin** his length is 17, **vin_data** the length is 3 and finally **vin_val** the length is 100.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment in the question, and looking at the input file, you could start with this.

```
01  VIN-RECORD.
    05  VIN                 PIC X(17).
    05  VIN-COUNT           PIC S9(5) COMP-3.
    05  VIN-VALUE           PIC X(100).
```

I'm guessing that the second field is COMP-3 based on the six examples all ending with a C byte.  This indicates a positive COMP-3 value.  A D byte would be a negative COMP-3 value.  An F byte would indicate an unsigned COMP-3 value.

The third field is variable length and right padded with spaces.

Answer (score 2):

> how to define a copybook file of ebcdic data?

You don't.

A copybook may be used as a record definition (=*how* the data is stored), it has nothing to do with the encoding of data that may be stored in that.

This leaves the question "How do I define the record structure?"

You'd need the amount of fields, their length and type (it likely is not only `USAGE DISPLAY`) and then just define it with some fancy names. Ideally you just get the original record definition from the COBOL program writing the file, put that into a copybook if it isn't in one yet, and use that.

Your link has [samples](https://github.com/AbsaOSS/cobrix/tree/master/examples/example_data) that show actually how a copybook looks like, if you struggle on the definition then please edit your question with the copybook you've defined and we may be able to help.